# Does text in brackets invoke the "an" vs. "a" rule?

Tags: grammaticality, parentheses

I saw the following sentence today:

> It has a (admittedly poor) government.

I agree that without the text in brackets, this sentence is correct:

> It has a government.

But when I read the original sentence, I want to change it to:

> It has an (admittedly poor) government.

My question is, **when deciding "an" vs. "a", do I consider text insight brackets or not?**

Comment: What I have seen in the past, _not universally_, is something like "... has a(n admittedly poor) government...".

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* consider the brackets.  When in doubt, read what you write aloud. and you may be surprised how useful this technique is at flushing out bad English.

But beware of "an hotel".  I always refer to "a hotel" but there are wierd people, the unfortunate victims of expensive educations, that sometimes insist on "an hotel", as if they might go into a pub and ask for "an half of bitter".

Gotta love English.

Comment: I suspect that those who go to "an hotel" or have "an half of bitter" do so because in their dialect, the "h" in both words is silent.

Comment: Check your weird spelling @Aethelbald! But +1 for the "an hotel" - I agree, but dropping h is really popular these days, especially with "historic": "an historic day".

Comment: [Four candles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Candles) anyone?

Comment: @Jeff, agreed about the dialect.  I'm talking aboutprivileged types who use Received Pronunciation.  They will write about an hotel and thenorder a half of bitter. THey have another and soon become as pissed as an ewt.